# How can I read a text file from HDFS into Python, and save the content in a string?

Tags: python, string, file, load, hdfs

I have a .txt file saved in HDFS, and I want to read it in Python and save the content in a string variable. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

you can use pyhdfs package for downloading the file from the HDFS server and then read the file and load it in a string variable

```
import pyhdfs
hdfsclient = pyhdfs.HdfsClient('HDFS_URL')

# to copy from HDFS SERVER
hdfsclient.copy_to_local(HDFS_source_file_path, LOCAL_target_file_path)

file = open(“local_file.txt”, “r”) 
String_var = file.read() 

# to copy to the HDFS SERVER
hdfsclient.copy_from_local(LOCAL_source_file_path, HDFS_target_file_path)
```